# How do you get Plantuml to render uml for an existing project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, plantuml

Steps I've taken:

1. I have installed the plantuml plugin into Android Studio 1.5.1 on a Windows 7 Pro PC.
2. I then installed Graphviz and set it's dot path and created the Graphviz environment variable.
3. I have restarted EVERYTHING. :)  Just in case.
4. I have opened a small Android Project.
5. I found PlantUML windows and can open it.

How do you generate (reverse generate?) a UML diagram of the existing project?
Or even of a particular java file?

Comment: Do you expect that this is created automatically from code ? This is not the way plantuml works, you have to use its Meta language.

Comment: Did you find an alternative that generates UMLs from existing project?